# Is it possible to set an instance variable for a function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have a function with a variable duration inside it.

Is there any way to set the Duration` value outside of the function in some other nonparent function without adjusting any parameter?

Comment: From outside `slowAction` or `make_slow`?

Comment: Yes sorry if I was not clear. I want to adjust the value in a function completely separate from this one where I call this function.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. Why can't you use a parameter?

Comment: `slowDuration` is declared inside `slowAction` and as such it will shadow any variable with the same name that is declared outside this function. Further, you initialize it to `None` and then call `slowDuration -=1`. It will be difficult to guess what you were trying to do there. In addition to showing us *how* you tried to implement something, it would be a good idea to also explain to us *what* is it that you were trying to do.

Comment: It is a project so we are not allowed to adjust any of the parameters.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is override a function in another class, but only for a set amount of turns. I call a separate function to apply the duration in the other class.

Answer (score 2):

With Python 3.x you can declare it with the `nonlocal` keyword

```
def make_slow(action):
    slowDuration = None

    def slowAction(self, colony):
        nonlocal slowDuration
        slowDuration = 10 # It is changing the variable from the scope above
```

If you want to change a value from somewhere else and you mustn't return the value, try going `global`... Note this may pollute your current namespace.

For a more pythonic approach, you should use something like `self.slowDuration`. That's what objects are for.

Answer (score 1):

`slowDuration` is a local variable of the `slowAction` function. The point of local variables is that they are only accessible inside the function.

You should change the `slowAction` function so it uses a `slowDuration` variable that is defined somewhere else, for example as a member variable of the class that `make_slow` apparently belongs to.

You can also make `slowAction` be an instance of a class that overrides the `__call__` method.

```
>>> class Counter:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.count = 0
...     def __call__(self, delta):
...         self.count += delta
...         print(self.count)
...     def set_count(self, c):
...         self.count = c
... 
>>> c = Counter()
>>> c(1)
1
>>> c(3)
4
>>> c(3)
7
>>> c(3)
10
>>> c.set_count(42)
>>> c(-2)
40
```

You could also use some trickery to make the shared variable available on the function object itself:

```
def makeCounter():
    counter = None
    def counter_func():
        counter.count += 1
        print(counter.count)
    counter = counter_func
    counter.count = 0
    return counter
```

and use it like this:

```
>>> c = makeCounter()
>>> c()
1
>>> c()
2
>>> c()
3
>>> c()
4
>>> c.count = 42
>>> c()
43
>>> c()
44
>>> c()
45
```

But in general, "clever" code like that should be avoided unless you have a very good reason to use it, because it makes the code base harder to understand.